# How do I get a PHP class constructor to call its parent's parent's constructor?

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, constructor

I need to have a class constructor in PHP call its parent's **parent's** (grandparent?) constructor without calling the parent constructor.

```
// main class that everything inherits
class Grandpa 
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

}

class Papa extends Grandpa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // call Grandpa's constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Kiddo extends Papa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO CALL GRANDPA'S
        // CONSTRUCTOR AND NOT PAPA'S
    }
}
```

I know this is a bizarre thing to do and I'm attempting to find a means that doesn't smell bad but nonetheless, I'm curious if it's possible.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just instantiate Grandpa inside of Kiddo's construct?

Comment: The Grampa constructor sets properties for itself that are inherited by its children.  Papa does some stuff in it's constructor that will mess up Kiddo. So I need the call to Grandpa constructor to set properties for Kiddo during construction.

Comment: Then shouldn't Kiddo extend from Grandpa and not Papa.

Comment: @MitMaro. I agree and I actually solved my actual problem by creating an intermediate class that extended Grandpa. Then both Papa and Kiddo extended that class. Kiddo required some intermediate functionality of Papa but didn't like it's constructor so the class has that additional functionality and both extend it.

Comment: A perfect solution. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Changed the accepted answer to the one that truly resolves the question being asked.

Comment: what if the grandparent class is abstract?

Answer (score 220, accepted):

The ugly workaround would be to pass a boolean param to Papa indicating that you do not wish to parse the code contained in it's constructor.  i.e:

```
// main class that everything inherits
class Grandpa 
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

}

class Papa extends Grandpa
{
    public function __construct($bypass = false)
    {
        // only perform actions inside if not bypassing
        if (!$bypass) {

        }
        // call Grandpa's constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Kiddo extends Papa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $bypassPapa = true;
        parent::__construct($bypassPapa);
    }
}
```

Comment: good workaround, but it is not acceptable if the parent class comes from some external library wish you with to extend. I like the too much php answer below.

Comment: That's actually quite clever. In my implementation I do `if($bypass) return;` & can position it so some important stuff gets done before the bypass.

Answer (score 90):

You must use `Grandpa::__construct()`, there's no other shortcut for it. Also, this ruins the encapsulation of the `Papa` class - when reading or working on `Papa`, it should be safe to assume that the `__construct()` method will be called during construction, but the `Kiddo` class does not do this.

Comment: Can't understand how. Declaring __construct as static results in the following error for me "Fatal error: Constructor Grandpa::__construct() cannot be static" under PHP5.3

Comment: When I tried it, I didn't declare it as static. I created the class structure normally but instead of calling parent::__construct(), I called Grandpa::__construct() and it worked. I doesn't seem right to me either but this whole question got kinda weird.

Comment: Agreed. I use this all the time - you can call a class by it's name, not just via the magic names of `parent` or `self`. I have been known to go three or four classes deep. In fact, I've started referring to my base class by it's name rather than using parent, that way I'm sure I'm getting the right object, always.

Comment: EvilChookie`s solusion is the best. Should be the approved answer. Than you Chookie!

Comment: In php when you call a function using static operator `::` from an object context it will be called using the object context which is completely fkd-up. At least in JS (about the `this` madness) it uses the callee context.

Comment: @SparK If you are using PHP 5.3.0 or later, [Late Static Bindings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) would most likely solve your use case.

Answer (score 58):

```
class Grandpa 
{
    public function __construct()
    {}
}

class Papa extends Grandpa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //call Grandpa's constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Kiddo extends Papa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //this is not a bug, it works that way in php
        Grandpa::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't choose to do this as it means Papa's contractor won't get called at all. I'd go with something like cballou's approach (i.e. of passing an argument to  Papa's constructor and having it invoke *it's* parents constructor or not based on that).

Comment: The situation we are in here is in such a way that we need to skip the parent's logic and in most of the cases we can't change the grandparent or the parent classes. I believe this is the best way to do it as there are changes made only in the child. The only issue is that it might throw an E_STRICT notice [link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42016), it didn't for me though when I tested it.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, however, if you *really* don't need the logic of the parent's constructor, are you sure that you are really making a subsclass of a parent?

Comment: This is the correct answer. While it may seem silly to inherit Papa but you want to call the GrandPa constructor without Papa, I've found it useful to be do. I want to keep the hierarchy, but I need to do a clean Kiddo constructor that doesn't have anything to do with Papa, but still want the benefits of using what's going on in GrandPa's constructor. Maybe Papa is doing a bunch of junk in the constructor that isn't needed or wanted by Kiddo, but it still has useful components.

Comment: Just called grandpa like I'm the boss

Answer (score 29):

Beautiful solution using `Reflection`.

```
<?php
class Grandpa 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Grandpa's constructor called\n";
    }

}

class Papa extends Grandpa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Papa's constructor called\n";

        // call Grandpa's constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Kiddo extends Papa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Kiddo's constructor called\n";

        $reflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod(get_parent_class(get_parent_class($this)), '__construct');
        $reflectionMethod->invoke($this);
    }
}

$kiddo = new Kiddo();
$papa = new Papa();
```

Answer (score 21):

I ended up coming up with an alternative solution that solved the problem.

- I created an intermediate class that extended Grandpa.
- Then both Papa and Kiddo extended that class.
- Kiddo required some intermediate functionality of Papa but didn't like it's constructor so the class has that additional functionality and both extend it.

I've upvoted the other two answers that provided valid yet ugly solutions for an uglier question:)

Comment: I think the better idea here is to break the functionality you are trying to use out of the constructed and into a protected method. Then you can call that method from a constructor selectively

Comment: This does not answer the exact question you've phrased. This happens if the real world muddies up something which should be clear and confined. It's a pity for this question.

Answer (score 16):

Another option that doesn't use a flag and might work in your situation:

```
<?php
// main class that everything inherits
class Grandpa 
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->GrandpaSetup();
    }

    public function GrandpaSetup(){
        $this->prop1 = 'foo';
        $this->prop2 = 'bar';
    }
}

class Papa extends Grandpa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // call Grandpa's constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->prop1 = 'foobar';
    }

}
class Kiddo extends Papa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->GrandpaSetup();
    }
}

$kid = new Kiddo();
echo "{$kid->prop1}\n{$kid->prop2}\n";
```

Answer (score 9):

I agree with "too much php", try this:

```
class Grandpa 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Grandpa<br/>';
    }

}

class Papa extends Grandpa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Papa<br/>';
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Kiddo extends Papa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO CALL GRANDPA'S
        // CONSTRUCTOR AND NOT PAPA'S
        echo 'Kiddo<br/>';
        Grandpa::__construct();
    }
}

$instance = new Kiddo;
```

I got the result as expected:

> > Kiddo
> >
> > Grandpa

This is a feature not a bug, check this for your reference:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42016

> > It is just the way it works. If it sees it is coming from the right context this call version does not enforce a static call.
> >
> > Instead it will simply keep $this and be happy with it.

parent::method() works in the same way, you don't have to define the method as static but it can be called in the same context. Try this out for more interesting:

```
class Grandpa 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Grandpa<br/>';
        Kiddo::hello();
    }

}

class Papa extends Grandpa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Papa<br/>';
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Kiddo extends Papa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO CALL GRANDPA'S
        // CONSTRUCTOR AND NOT PAPA'S
        echo 'Kiddo<br/>';
        Grandpa::__construct();
    }

    public function hello()
    {
        echo 'Hello<br/>';
    }
}

$instance = new Kiddo;
```

It also works as expected:

> > Kiddo
> >
> > Grandpa
> >
> > Hello

But if you try to initialize a new Papa, you will get an E_STRICT error:

```
$papa = new Papa;
```

> > Strict standards: Non-static method Kiddo::hello() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

You can use instanceof to determine if you can call a Children::method() in a parent method:

```
if ($this instanceof Kiddo) Kiddo::hello();
```

Comment: Just remember that parent is only a shortcut to whatever first parent that implemented the method… Thus from a descendant calling `AscendantName::method` works and from an ascendant calling `static::method` will always call the latest generation that implemented the method. And you may check not to call yourself using `(get_class($this)==__CLASS__?'Healthy people dont\'t call themself…':'Calling latest')` if you'd like parents to call kid methods (seems strange but might be usefull combined with private function and __call magic function )…

Answer (score 8):

There's an easier solution for this, but it requires that you know exactly how much inheritance your current class has gone through.  Fortunately, get_parent_class()'s arguments allow your class array member to be the class name as a string as well as an instance itself.

Bear in mind that this also inherently relies on calling a class' __construct() method statically, though within the instanced scope of an inheriting object the difference in this particular case is negligible (ah, PHP).

Consider the following:

```
class Foo {
    var $f = 'bad (Foo)';

    function __construct() {
        $this->f = 'Good!';
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    var $f = 'bad (Bar)';
}

class FooBar extends Bar {
    var $f = 'bad (FooBar)';

    function __construct() {
        # FooBar constructor logic here
        call_user_func(array(get_parent_class(get_parent_class($this)), '__construct'));
    }
}

$foo = new FooBar();
echo $foo->f; #=> 'Good!'
```

Again, this isn't a viable solution for a situation where you have no idea how much inheritance has taken place, due to the limitations of debug_backtrace(), but in controlled circumstances, it works as intended.

Answer (score 7):

You can call Grandpa::__construct from where you want and the $this keyword will refer to your current class instance. <strike>But be carefull with this method you cannot access to protected properties and methods of current instance from this other context, only to public elements.</strike> => All work and [officialy supported](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42016).

Example

```
// main class that everything inherits
class Grandpa 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo $this->one; // will print 1
        echo $this->two; // error cannot access protected property
    }

}

class Papa extends Grandpa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // call Grandpa's constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Kiddo extends Papa
{
    public $one = 1;
    protected $two = 2;
    public function __construct()
    {
        Grandpa::__construct();
    }
}

new Kiddo();
```

Answer (score 7):

Funny detail about php: extended classes can use non-static functions of a parent class in a static matter. Outside you will get a strict error.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class GrandPa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        print("construct grandpa<br/>");
        $this->grandPaFkt();
    }

    protected function grandPaFkt(){
        print(">>do Grandpa<br/>");
    }
}

class Pa extends GrandPa
{
    public function __construct()
    {   parent::__construct();
        print("construct Pa <br/>");
    }

    public function paFkt(){
        print(">>do Pa <br>");
    }
}

class Child extends Pa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        GrandPa::__construct();
        Pa::paFkt();//allright
        //parent::__construct();//whatever you want
        print("construct Child<br/>");
    }

}

$test=new Child();
$test::paFkt();//strict error
```

So inside a extended class (Child) you can use

```
parent::paFkt();
```

or

```
Pa::paFkt();
```

to access a parent (or grandPa's) (not private) function.

Outside class def

```
$test::paFkt();
```

will trow strict error (non static function).

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

class grand_pa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Hey I am Grand Pa <br>";
    }
}

class pa_pa extends grand_pa
{
    // no need for construct here unless you want to do something specifically within this class as init stuff
    // the construct for this class will be inherited from the parent.
}

class kiddo extends pa_pa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo "Hey I am a child <br>";
    }
}

new kiddo();
?>
```

Of course this expects you do not need to do anything within the construct of the pa_pa. Running this will output :

Hey I am Grand Pa
Hey I am a child

Answer (score 2):

Ok, Yet another ugly solution:

Create a function in Papa like:

```
protected function call2Granpa() {
     return parent::__construct();
}
```

Then in Kiddo you use:

`parent::call2Granpa();` //instead of calling constructor in Papa.

I think it could work... I haven't test it, so I'm not sure if the
objects are created correctly.

I used this approach but with non-constructor functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
// main class that everything inherits
class Grandpa 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->___construct();
    }

    protected function ___construct()
    {
        // grandpa's logic
    }

}

class Papa extends Grandpa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // call Grandpa's constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Kiddo extends Papa
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::___construct();
    }
}
```

note that "___construct" is not some magic name, you can call it "doGrandpaStuff".

Answer (score 1):

```
    class Grandpa 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo"Hello Kiddo";
    }    
}

class Papa extends Grandpa
{
    public function __construct()
    {            
    }
    public function CallGranddad()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Kiddo extends Papa
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function needSomethingFromGrandDad
    {
       parent::CallGranddad();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

from php 7 u can use

`parent::parent::__construct();`

Comment: @Wouter0100 lala977 did say "From PHP 7" which your link is using 5.6

Comment: @TravisWeston please recheck my link. it tests that peace of code against all versions. 5.6 up to 7.2 reproduce the same error, while other runtimes return some different errors.