# Creating a new TinyMCE form widget

Tags: forms, symfony1, tinymce, widget

I'm using tinyMCE in my forms and have noticed that I only use two configurations : a very limited one, for things like comments, and a more complex one, for the administators of the site.

For the moment I do that by repeating this sort of code in each form :

```
    //TinyMCE
    $this->widgetSchema['comment'] = new sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE(array(
      'width'  => 550,
      'height' => 150,
      'config' => '
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,separator,bullist,separator,link, sub,sup,separator,charmap",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_path : false,
    language : "fr"
'
    ));
```

Could I (and how) create two widgets, say TinyMCEsmall and TinyMCEfull so that I don't have to repeat code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
class sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCESmall extends sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE
{
  protected function configure($options = array(), $attributes = array())
  {
    parent::configure($options, $attributes);

    //assuming there are no options on the parent class that you need, call setOptions. If you need to retain some, make individual setOption calls.
    $this->addOption('width', 550);
    $this->addoption('height', 150);
    $this->addOption('config', '
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,separator,bullist,separator,link, sub,sup,separator,charmap",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
theme_advanced_path : false,
language : "fr"
');
  }
}
```

Note that options you pass in will still take precedence.

Comment: I get an error : "sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCESmall does not support the following option: 'label'."

Comment: Looks like calling setOptions overwrites the options like "label" that sfWidgetForm use. That should fix it.

Comment: that's weird. the new version doesn't cause any errors, but I have a tinyMCE textarea with the default options.

Comment: I'm not sure why that wouldn't work. You can try individual addOption calls for each option. There is no "addOptions" method.

Answer (score -1):

sure, create a class that extends the sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE and put your specifics in its constructor.

put it in let's say a var called myTinyMCE

and call at last in the constructor the parent::constructor(myTinyMCE)

where you give the setup as a parameter.

then in the form don't call the sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE anymore, but your class you created...

```
class myClass extends sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE { 

public class __construct(){
      myTinyMCE = array(
      'width'  => 550,
      'height' => 150,
      'config' => '
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,separator,bullist,separator,link, sub,sup,separator,charmap",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_path : false,
    language : "fr"
'
    );

  parent::__construct(myTinyMCE);

 }

}
```

more info on that can be found here [How do I get a PHP class constructor to call its parent's parent's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557608/how-do-i-get-a-php-class-constructor-to-call-its-parents-parents-constructor)

Comment: This is not the proper way to do this in Symfony.