# PHP OOP inheritance order

Tags: php, oop

Why child class is not going inside parents constructor method ? what change should i make to get the constructor method executed of A, B, C in order when i run `$obj = new C();`

```
<?php

class A
{

    function A()
    {
        echo "I am the constructor of A. (Grand Parent)<br />\n";
    }
}

class B extends A
{

    function B()
    {
        echo "I am the constructor of B. (Parent)<br />\n";
    }
}

class C extends B
{

    function C()
    {
        echo "I am the constructor of C. (Child)<br />\n";
    }
}

$obj = new C();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: you're using a deprecated syntax for your classes. You should be using the `__construct()` function for constructors.

Secondly, PHP does not implicitly call a parent constructor if one is defined in a child. This means you need to call it yourself.

Combining these two ideas we get:

```
<?php

class A
{
   function __construct()
    {
        echo "I am the constructor of A. (Grand Parent)<br />\n";
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo "I am the constructor of B. (Parent)<br />\n";
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class C extends B
{
    function __construct()
    {
        echo "I am the constructor of C. (Child)<br />\n";
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

$obj = new C();
?>
```

The PHP reference is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#object.construct). Note that the old syntax has compatibility issues with namespaced classes from PHP 5.3.3 onwards. You should change your syntax for new code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly call parent class constructor like this `parent::__construct();`. So now you can call class B constructor inside class C and class A constructor inside class B. 
Hope this help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the constructors of the parents explicitly.

```
<?php

class A
{

    function A()
    {
        echo "I am the constructor of A. (Grand Parent)<br />\n";
    }
}

class B extends A
{

    function B()
    {
        A::__construct();   // Like this
        echo "I am the constructor of B. (Parent)<br />\n";
    }
}

class C extends B
{

    function C()
    {
        B::__construct();   // Like this
        echo "I am the constructor of C. (Child)<br />\n";
    }
}

$obj = new C();
?>
```

And you can find some workarounds **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557608/how-do-i-get-a-php-class-constructor-to-call-its-parents-parents-constructor)**