# PHP, How maintain parent class data into child class?

Tags: php, wordpress, class, plugins, extends

So, I finally found a way to affect the desired function.

The function I was trying to modify is contained in a class so, I did something like this:

```
class my_Check extends Appointments {

   function __construct() {
      $this->unregister_parent_hook();
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_confirmation', array( $this, 'post_confirmation' ) );
      add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_confirmation', array( $this, 'post_confirmation' ) );
   }

   function unregister_parent_hook() {
      global $appointments;  //this was the object created with the parent class
      remove_action( 'wp_ajax_post_confirmation', array( $appointments, 'post_confirmation' ) );
      remove_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_confirmation', array( $appointments, 'post_confirmation' ) );
   }

   function post_confirmation() {

        ...do the stuff with my mods...

   }
}

$new_Check = new my_Check();
```

Only, I have a new problem now.  The parent class does a lot more in the `__construct()` (many `add_action()'s`, etc. And `$this` is populated with a lot of data).  The problem is, these other things and data do not seem to be carrying over into the child class.  I tried adding a `parent::__construct()` in the child's `__construct()` function, but that did not seem to work.

The code with my mods works except for things that need more data in the `$this` carried over from the parent class.

How can I maintain all the parent class's variable, functions, hooks & filters, etc. into the child class?

And, I can't really change the file with the parent class because that is in a plugin core file which I don't want to modify directly.

Comment: Can we see the parent::__construct method? Does it require any arguments to be passed to it? In fact, could you post the whole parent class?

Comment: Since the whole parent class is several thousand lines long, here is a link to the file with the parent class:    http://www.mokyoworks.com/appointments.zip

Answer (score 1):

I had seen many examples where people were using `parent::__construct()` to pass the parent's variables, etc. and they were placing it in the child's class `__construct()` function.  That wasn't working for me.

However, I was finally able to get it to work by calling the parent constructor within the new function I was adding to the parent class.  Like this:

```
function post_confirmation() {

    parent::__construct();

    ...do the stuff with my mods...
}
```

Got the solution from this post > https://stackoverflow.com/a/32232406/1848815