# PHP Error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method - PHP 5.2 to PHP 7

Tags: php

Running into a fatal error I'm at a loss to solve.
This code worked on PHP 5.2 but fails on PHP 7.  Full disclosure: I know very little about PHP.

Note: "CHtmlUsersListInt" is in a encrypted file I don't have the ability to open.  The encrypted file is open as other parts of the site work fine that rely on it, this seems to be my one last standing problem to move to a new server.

```
include("./_include/core/main_start.php"); 
    /* 
        Encrypted file that is opened and used in other parts of the site.
        "CHtmlUsersListInt" lives here.                
    */

class CHtmlUsersListAction extends CHtmlUsersListInt
{

    function CHtmlUsersListAction($name, $html_path)
    {
        $this->CHtmlUsersListInt($name, $html_path); /* LINE THROWING ERROR */
    }
}

$type = get_param("display", "list");
if ($type == "list") $list = new CHtmlUsersListAction("users_list", $g['tmpl']['dir_tmpl_main'] . "_mail_interest.html");
else
{
    redirect("mail.php");
}
```

Line that throws error:

```
$this->CHtmlUsersListInt($name, $html_path);
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method CHtmlUsersListAction::CHtmlUsersListInt()

Comment: It would be helpful for you to reduce the size of this example to the minimum necessary to demonstrate your problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is not possible unless the `CHtmlUsersListAction` class was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the problem line is attempting to call the parent class constructor.

Because of the length of your example, and the complication of the encrypted file, I will not be able to reproduce this on my own machine. However, you can try replacing the line

```
$this->CHtmlUsersListInt($name, $html_path); /* LINE THROWING ERROR */
```

with this:

```
$parent->CHtmlUsersListInt($name, $html_path);
```

or this:

```
parent::CHtmlUsersListInt($name, $html_path);
```

or even this:

```
parent::__construct($name, $html_path);
```

For more examples, you can reference this very good question:

[How do I get a PHP class constructor to call its parent's parent's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1557608/2657515)

Comment: Jon, many thanks.  You are a prince among men.  The one that worked: parent::CHtmlUsersListInt($name, $html_path);