# Is this PHP pseudo-DI pattern wrong / dangerous?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, constructor

I have let's say a class, VehicleManager.
This class manages the lifecycle and calling of Vehicle type Objects. Vehicles act as modules and extend the base Vehicle class, which is abstract.

So if you make a class bike, you never do new Bike(), you do VehicleManager->create('Bike',5);

My problem is, i want the construction of every vehicle to receive predefined parameters,and do some predefined actions, so my base Vehicle class has a private final constructor.

Example:

```
final private function __construct(Array $myCustomData){
  $this->customData = $myCustomData;
}
```

But still i want each vehicle type to have some custom initializion

So after doing

```
$newVehicle = new $ClassName($myCustomData);
```

Im doing

```
$newVehicle->initialize();
```

Is this acceptable? Thanks

Comment: you know you can override `__construct` and _still_ call the base implementation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557608/how-do-i-get-a-php-class-constructor-to-call-its-parents-parents-constructor?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Could you elaborate? The __construct method is final in my base class. And i am checking that the class provided extends that beforehand.

Comment: well, you could just make it non-final... The question I linked contains many thoughts on this. I just thought I'd throw it in as an alternative, that might suite your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several patterns to generate vehicle in your project, take a look at AbstractFactory or FactoryMethod. They can be used depending on your program context. This is AbstractFactory example:

```
// Vehicle classes
class Vehicle
{
};

class Car extends Vehicle
{
};

class Bike extends Vehicle
{
};

//Abstract factory classes
abstract class VehicleFactory
{
    abstract protected function GetVehicle( $customData );
};

class CarFactory extends VehicleFactory
{
    public function GetVehicle( $customData )
    {
        //Do special init
        return new Car();
    }
};

class BikeFactory extends VehicleFactory
{
    public function GetVehicle( $customData )
    {
        //Do special init
        return new Bike();
    }
};
//Program context classes
class RaceTrack
{
    public function GenerateRacers( VehicleFactory $factory )
    {
        //$factory->GetVehicle(array());
    }
    public function AddRacers( Vehicle $vehicle )
    {
    }
};
$CarFact = new CarFactory();
$RaceTrack = new RaceTrack();
$RaceTrack->GenerateRacers($CarFact);
```

This is example for Factory method:

```
//Factory method pattern
class VehicleFactory2
{
    const BIKE_TYPE = 0;
    const CAR_TYPE = 1;

    public function GetVehicle( $type, $customData )
    {
        if ( $type == self::BIKE_TYPE )
        {
            return new Bike($customData);
        }
        else if ( $type == self::CAR_TYPE )
        {
            return new Car($customData);
        }

        return null;
    }
};

$VehicleFact = new VehicleFactory2();
$RaceTrack2 = new RaceTrack();
$RaceTrack2->AddRacers($VehicleFact->GetVehicle(VehicleFactory2::CAR_TYPE, array()));
```

DI can be used as constructor , method, setter injections. It's good practice to use DI to make your project more flexible