# Call to a member function prepare() on null use oop classes

Tags: php, oop

In DB.class.php this is my database constructor"

```
private $database;
private $error;
private $stmt;

public function __construct()
{
    $dsn = ...;
    $options = array (
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION 
    );

    try {
        $this->database = new PDO("$dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options");

    } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
        echo "error";
    }
}

public function builder(string $sql)
{
    $this->stmt = $this->database->prepare($sql);
    $this->stmt->execute();

    if (!$stmt) {
        exit("Database query failed . . . !");
    }
    return $stmt;
}
```

and this is my User.class.php which is extended, my database class:

```
public function logIn()
{
    $sql = "SELECT...;"
    $login = parent::builder($sql);
    //vardump($login);
    $data = $login->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($login->rowCount() == 1) {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
        Redirect::to('index.php');
    } else {
        echo "Incorrect user and pass . . .";
        exit();
    }
}
```

this is my child constructor

```
public function __construct(array $args = [])
{
    $this->username = $args['username'] ?? '';
    $this->email = $args['email'] ?? '';
    $this->phone_number = $args['phone_number'] ?? '';
    $this->password = $args['password'] ?? '';
    $this->photo = $args['photo'] ?? '';
    $this->gender = $args['gender'] ?? '';
}
```

when I var dump $login I get an error ((Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null)) how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Show your `__construct` method from child class `User.class.php`. If it exists, you must necessarily call `parent::__construct();` in it.

Comment: Just a design thing - is your User class really a *type of* DB class.  Would it more naturally use this class.  Using the DB class is a more common design than you are currently using.

Comment: yeah, as I said - just add `parent::__construct();` to your child constructor for fill `$this->database` by parent. But @NigelRen said correct - for good code design your User-class must only use DB-class as object to query and not be his child.

Comment: If `User` extends `DB`... why do you call `parent::builder()`? Are you overriding builder and for some reason need to call the inherited one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a PHP class constructor to call its parent's parent's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557608/how-do-i-get-a-php-class-constructor-to-call-its-parents-parents-constructor)

Comment: @yivi I just what to solve my problem and i don't know how? would you please help?

Comment: Grabuti already told you what to do. The linked dupe just repeats the same advise.