# php constructor is not working properly in program

Tags: php, class, oop, constructor

Please refer this
[Code input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRA5K.png)

This code doesn't give the expected output

```
class User{
        protected $name;
        protected $age;

        public function __construct($name, $age){
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->age = $age;
        }
    }

    class Customer extends User{
        private $balance;

        public function __construct($name, $age, $balance){
            $this->balance = $balance;
        }

        public function pay($amount){
            return $this->name . ' paid $' . $amount;
        }
    }

    $customer1 = new Customer('Adithya', 23, 50);
    echo $customer1->pay(100);
```

It only gives this
Can someone please explain the reason?

Comment: Because you never call the parent class's construct function.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I call it.

Comment: `parent::__construct($params, $go, $here)`.  Also, we don't accept images of code here.  I already formatted your code block from earlier, but in the future you need to do that yourself.

Comment: You need to call parent class's construct function parent::__construct(); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557608/how-do-i-get-a-php-class-constructor-to-call-its-parents-parents-constructor

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow adithya! it would be best if you check on [php's manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). you can call `User`'s constructor in `Customer`'s constructor using `parent::__construct()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    class Customer extends User{
    private $balance;

    public function __construct($name, $age, $balance){
        $this->balance = $balance;
        parent::__construct($name,$age,$balance);
    }

    public function pay($amount){
        return $this->name . ' paid $' . $amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line to the Customer class constructor so that the parent class constructor is called with the right parameters

```
parent::__construct($name, $age);
```

So the code is as follows

(I have `added a line in the pay method` to make it more **meaningful**)

```
<?php
class User{
        protected $name;
        protected $age;

        public function __construct($name, $age){
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->age = $age;
        }
    }

    class Customer extends User{
        private $balance;

        public function __construct($name, $age, $balance){
            parent::__construct($name, $age);
            $this->balance = $balance;
        }

        public function pay($amount){
            $this->balance = $this->balance - $amount;
            return $this->name . ' paid ' . $amount;
        }

        public function getbalance(){
            return $this->name . ' now has ' . $this->balance ;
        }

    }

    $customer1 = new Customer('Adithya', 23, 50);
    echo $customer1->pay(100);

    echo "<br>";

    echo $customer1->getbalance();
    ?>
```

The display will be :

```
Adithya paid 100
Adithya now has -50
```

(initially Adithya is having 50 as balance, but he has paid 100, so the new balance is -50)